# Electron: Global script that runs on all html pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a web based project consisting of a couple hundred html pages. Now I would like to wrap it into an electron app. The problem is that jQuery for instance doesn't run inside that app unless I add this line before the jQuery script tag:

```
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
```

and this line after the jQuery script tag:

```
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

Is there a way to make this work without modifying all these hundreds of pages? Could I for instance somehow specify a global script (sort of like a browser extension with content scripts) that takes care of this for me? I mean after all electron embeds a chromium, right?

Comment: does preload script works for you?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Check browserwindow docs for webPreferences.preload option.